# Total possible combinations by dividing a group into two teams

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From A first course in probability by Sheldon Ross, 8th Edition -

> In order to play a game of basketball, 10 children at a playground divide themselves into two teams of 5 each. How many different divisions are possible?

From my understanding this would be calculated as : $\large {10 \choose {5}} \times{ (10 - 5) \choose {5}} = {10 \choose{5, \hspace{0.1cm}5}} = \frac{10!}{5!5!} = 252$

However, in the book, the author says that the order of the two teams is irrelevant $\hspace{0.1cm}\therefore$ the actual answer  $\large = \frac{252}{2} = 126$

Why divide by 2? Is it because my original formula is also permuting the two teams with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calculating no. Of ways of choosing 5 people from 10. So you can call them say team A. But, you are counting each 'division' twice as by division, we mean that only groups of people matter, not group name. So when you choose other 5 members as team A, it is same division as when you called them team B